# Dynamically add nested property to ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I'm getting a JSON object (may contain multiple levels of JSON arrays and such) which I want to translate into an ExpandoObject.

I figured out how to add simple properties to an ExpandoObject at runtime as it implements IDictionary, but how do I add *nested* properties (for example, something like `myexpando.somelist.anotherlist.someitem`) **at runtime** that will resolve correctly?

**Edit:** Currently this works for simple (first level) properties well:

```
var exo = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;
exo.Add(name, value);
```

The question is how to get the name to be nested and the ExpandoObject to resolve accordingly.

Comment: Alex, considering your previous question, I think you need DynamicObject instead of ExpandoObject. See [this](http://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA) and its [samples](http://pastebin.com/JEYfgL3a)

Answer (score 9):

```
dynamic myexpando = new ExpandoObject();
myexpando.somelist = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
myexpando.somelist.anotherlist = new ExpandoObject() as dynamic;
myexpando.somelist.anotherlist.someitem = "Hey Hey There! I'm a nested value :D";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it like this:

```
var exo = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;
var nested1 = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<String, Object>;

exo.Add("Nested1", nested1);
nested1.Add("Nested2", "value");

dynamic d = exo;
Console.WriteLine(d.Nested1.Nested2); // Outputs "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by storing a reference to the previously retrieved object, or Dictionary, when `TryGetValue` is called. I use a class that looks like the following:

```
public DynamicFile(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
    _dictionary = dictionary;
    _lastGetRef = _dictionary;
}

private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _dictionary;
private IDictionary<string, object> _lastGetRef;

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
    if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result))
    {
        result = null;
        return true;
    }

    var dictionary = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
    if (dictionary != null)
    {
        result = new DynamicFile(dictionary);
        _lastGetRef = dictionary;
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
{
    if(_dictionary.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        _dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
    else if (_lastGetRef.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        _lastGetRef[binder.Name] = value;
    else
        _lastGetRef.Add(binder.Name, value);

    return true;
}
```

`_dictionary` is set by the constructor when the dynamic object is created and is then set as the immediate last reference dictionary. This works due to the fact that Dictionarys are classes and hence reference types.

To then nest correctly, you need to instantiate each dictionary at each nest level just like a multi-dimensional array. For example:

```
myexpando.somelist = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myexpando.somelist.anotherlist = new Dictionary<string, object>();
myexpando.somelist.anotherlist.someitem = "Hey Hey There! I'm a nested value :D";
```

You could probably write some code in `TryGetMember` that automatically adds a Dictionary when the key doesn't exist, but I didn't need that so I didn't add it.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy

**Extension**

```
public static class ObjectExtension
{
    public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object source)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(source);

        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
            expando.Add(item);

        return (ExpandoObject)expando;
    }
}
```

**Client Action**

```
    public IActionResult Client(string username)
    {
        var client = HttpContext.Items["profile"] as Client;

        var model = new
        {
            client.Id,
            client.Name,
            client.Surname,
            client.Username,
            client.Photo,
            CoverPhoto = new {
               client.CoverPhoto.Source,
               client.CoverPhoto.X
            }.ToExpando(),
        }.ToExpando();

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Client.cshtml**

```
<img id="cover-photo" src="@Model.CoverPhoto.Source" />
```